# Java: how to make an efficient chance method

Tags: java, performance, random

Hi there im making a rewards code and im trying to make a good chance code
i have this method for now,

```
 public int getRandom(int lower, int upper) {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt((upper - lower) + 1) + lower;
    }


int chance = getRandom(0, 100);
if(chance < 10){
reward(player)
}
```

Is there a better method can make this code more efficient? sometimes it get random chance within 0 and 10 which gives the best reward.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Creating a new Random object each call is is an unnecessary expense.

Comment: For example, there is a reward and it's on 10% chance getting it, in order to get this reward your chance would be under 10% which is a rare or legendary reward, this code sometimes gets a chance between 0, 10 easily is there any way to improve it?

Comment: Add another random chance, so if you get the first 10%, generate a second chance to filter it down further.  Random by it's nature is, random

Comment: For your use-case I would consider implementing a method `boolean isRandomPercentage(double)` which takes a `double` from `0.0` to `100.0`. You can then simply do `if (isRandomPercentage(10.0))` which is much more readable IMO.

Comment: Try `if(chance % 10 == 1)`

Comment: what do you mean with ***efficient*** and this ***sometimes it get random chance within 0 and 10 which gives the best reward***

Comment: Alright thanks for your help, I did read all comments they were really helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ThreadLocalRandom` which is faster than `Random`.  However, your code is already O(1), so it can't really be any more efficient.

You also might want to refrain from creating a new object every time the method is called.

Comment: I have done this which i think its better thanks.                                           public double getRandom(double lower, double upper) {
  return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble((upper - lower) + 1) + lower;
 }

Comment: @Yousif Raad: why did you switch from `int` to `double`? The suggestion is to switch from `Random` to `ThreadLocalRandom`, not anything else.